# Delete 'N' no lines only on the Nth occurrence of a pattern in a file using the sed/awk command

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I use below 'sed' command to delete 'N' no of lines after every match of a pattern in a file.

```
sed -i '/test/,+1d' file.txt
```

Suppose, I have a pattern 'test' in a file called file.txt. And I want to delete 2 lines only after the second occurrence of a word 'test'. Is there any sed/awk one liner for this?

Example: file.txt

```
test
apple
mango
test
brinjal
carrot
test
banana
gauva
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the second `test` and the line that follows it:

```
$ awk '/test/ && ++f == 2 {getline;next} 1' file.txt
test
apple
mango
carrot
test
banana
gauva
```

How it works:

1. `/test/ && ++f == 2 {getline;next}`

   Every time we meet line matching the regex `test`, we increment variable `f` and, if `f==2`, we read in another line with `getline` and then jump to start over on the `next` line.  This has the effect of discarding both the `test` line and the following line.
2. `1`

   For all other lines, we print the line.  (`1` is awk shorthand for print-the-line.)

#### Alternate

In this approach, we capture the line number of the second occurrence of the line matching `test` in the variable `N`.

We print a line only if `N` is not yet assigned or else if the current line is at least 2 lines after line number `N`.

```
$ awk '/test/ && ++f == 2 {N=NR} (!N) || NR>=N+2' file.txt
test
apple
mango
carrot
test
banana
gauva
```